# How to use express middleware in SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, middleware

I want to use one of the ExpressJS middleware in SailsJS application. Its the "express-limiter" module(which is a express middleware) for rate limiting an api using IP address. Normally in express we do:

```
app.use(limiter({ some parameters }))
```

How to I use this middleware or any other express middleware in SailsJS application? 
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

1. install the middleware `npm install --save express-limiter`
2. change the `config/http.js` file adding the express-limiter

   ```
   middleware: {
      order: [
         'express-limiter-key'
      ],
      'express-limiter-key' = require('express-limiter')
   }
   ```

---

> the `var limiter = require('limiter')` won't work since > `middleware.order`is simply a lookup, and will search only keywords in `middleware` object.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install your middle ware by `npm install --save yourMiddleware`
2. Go to  `sails.config.http.middleware`
3. on top place `var limiter = require('limiter')
4. Put `limiter` in the `order`, I suppose close to the top.

Comment: I tried the same thing but that middleware is not getting trigged.

Comment: is it necessary to put express middleware in the order array too?

Comment: Yes. You have to import it as I shown in answer and put it in the order as per point 4

Comment: what about the options?