# Prevent DOS and DDOS attack with sailjs app

Tags: node.js, sails.js, denial-of-service

I'm using sails js in developing a node js application and I want to apply some prevention for DOS and DDOS attack, I see "express-rate-limit" and "express-limiter" packages, In express it is easy to implement using

```
app.use(limiter({ some parameters }))
```

but how to implement using **sailsjs** app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use express middleware in SailsJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540852/how-to-use-express-middleware-in-sailsjs)

Comment: What about options?

Answer (score 1):

Use [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible), which is not bound to any framework.

Here is basic example:

```js
const opts = {
  points: 6, // 6 points
  duration: 1, // Per second
};

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(opts);

rateLimiter.consume(remoteAddress, 2) // consume 2 points
    .then((rateLimiterRes) => {
      // 2 points consumed
    })
    .catch((rateLimiterRes) => {
      // Not enough points to consume
    });
```

There are a lot more examples on a [package Wiki](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki).